# Lightbox not working in my wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, lightbox

I have developed a wordpress theme with header, footer, sidebar, index, page, single and 404.php files. Now I want to add a gallery with lightbox effect to my site. I have tried lightbox plus, WP jQuery Lightbox and a few more plugins but none of them seems to work.

Comment: It is impossible to provide any assistance, as you are providing no useful information at all. What error messages do you get using what code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you include `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in header.php? That's the hook that many plugins use to load scripts and CSS files.

And use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what's loading, or not.